# EdgeCollider2D wall not preventing objects from going off screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create an `EdgeCollider2D` script for my game. From the code below it is suppose to cover part of the left and right ends of the main camera. The left side wall is working and objects are prevented from moving left but the right side wall doesn't prevent objects from going off the screen. I am not too sure what's causing it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class GameEdgeScript : MonoBehaviour {

// lets make verticies for the edge collider 2d
List<Vector2> newVerticies = new List<Vector2>();
EdgeCollider2D col;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake () {

    col = gameObject.AddComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();

    Camera camera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera> ();
    Vector3 screenSize = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, camera.nearClipPlane));

    float height1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("spriteHigh").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite.rect.height/2;
    float height2 = Screen.height*((float)0.8) + GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("spriteLow").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite.rect.height/2;

    newVerticies.Add( (Vector2)camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, height1, camera.nearClipPlane)));
    newVerticies.Add( (Vector2)camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, height2, camera.nearClipPlane)));
    newVerticies.Add( (Vector2)camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, height2, camera.nearClipPlane))); // NOT BLOCKING OBJECTS AT THE RIGHT X VALUE (Screen.width)
    newVerticies.Add( (Vector2)camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, height1, camera.nearClipPlane)));// NOT BLOCKING OBJECTS AT THE RIGHT X VALUE (Screen.width)

    Debug.Log (Screen.width);

    getPointsToDebug ();

    setPoints ();

    for (int i = 0; i<col.points.Length; i++) {
        Debug.Log (col.points[i]);
    }


void getPointsToDebug() {
    foreach (Vector2 piste in col.points) {
        Debug.Log(piste);
    }
}

void setPoints() {
    col.points = newVerticies.ToArray();
    }

}
```

Comment: is your camera orthographic?

Comment: Solved. I just realised that I was calling all my other game objects in Start() methods with the exception of this one which was Awake(), so I changed it to Start() it's working.

Comment: Just what a simple mistake can cause... congrats